# Zoom of the equirectangular background

Tags: 3d-view

I'm a newbie to the Blender so maybe this question is lame, but I didn't find an answer here.

I've set the background equirectangular image (Streetview panorama) and add some object to the scene. When I rotate the viewport in the Shading mode, everything is fine, object follows the background. But when I zoom in or out, only viewport is zooming and the background stays fixed, so the object loses it's place at the background.

How to make the background always follow the object?

Comment: If you're talking about an HDRI environment background, the long and the short of it is you can't.  What people often do to overcome this, however, is to place a large sphere "around" your object (or scene) and map the background image to the sphere (Either as an unshaded input or through a weak emission shader). This gives you a little more control over how the background moves relative to the camera and objects.

Comment: Excellent idea, thank you Christopher!